# printf("%s\n") output differs from printf("%s")

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf, newline

This program is supposed to read a line of text from a .txt file and print only the words that are palindromes (in a separate .txt file).

Both the logic and the input/output work as intended, but the problem arises when i try to separate the output with a new line after every word. Here is the code snippet:

```
while((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {

  if (isalpha(c)) {
    word[i++] = tolower(c);
  }

  else {
    word[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s", word);
  }
```

Let's say that the input sentence is : Garry is riding a bike, and now Michael has joined him. When there is no new line after every word, the output is what is expected (letters only). But when I use

```
while((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {

  if (isalpha(c)) {
    word[i++] = tolower(c);
  }

  else {
    word[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", word); // new line after every word
 }
```

blank lines start appearing

Why is there a blank line between "bike" and "and"? This generally happens every time there are more than 1 non-letter characters in a sequence. If the assignment of the characters to "word" is incorrect, why is "`printf("%s", word)`" working?

Thank you for your feedback.

Note: I am a first-year student in Computer Science.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have a comma **AND** a space (none of which are alphabetic letters) between `"bike"` and `"and"`, that's why!!!

Comment: @barakmanos this looks to me like an answer.

Comment: @iharob: I agree, but while I was writing an answer on how to resolve the problem, someone had already mentioned it, so if I now add it to my answer then it will kinda look like I "stole" it (although my comment was published beforehand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
else
{
    word[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", word);
}
```

To this:

```
else if (i > 0)
{
    word[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", word);
    i = 0;
}
```

In order to skip cases of 2 or more consecutive non-alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the input

```
 bike, and
```

Here `,` will cause the first check to fail. Thus it falls to the `else` clause and prints a new line.

This is because `i` will be `0` and `word[i] = '\0';` will lead to a null string. Now that you are printing `"%s\n"` The line will be blank as expected.

Comment: And if he wants spaces he should check with `isspace(char c)` since `isalpha(' ')` returns `0`. May be the function he has to use is `isprint(char c)`?

Comment: Oh, i see. Thank you, it helped me understand what was wrong.

Comment: @StefanRendevski Good that you learnt your mistake. All the best for your journey in computer science.

Answer (score 2):

Your program treats each individual non-alpha character as a word separator. If you have several consequential separators in your input string, your program (as written) will assume that there are "empty" zero-length words between them. These "empty" words look as extra empty lines in your output (when you follow each word with `\n`).

This is exactly what happens when your program discovers the `,` sequence in your input string  (i.e a comma followed by a space). Both `,` and  characters are non-alpha characters. Both of them are separators, which means that your program actually sees it as `<comma><empty word><space>`. This empty word is your extra blank line in the output.

If you modify your input string to contain a `,,,,,` sequence you will see an extra empty line for each "empty word" between these commas.

These empty lines are visible only because you added the `\n` character after each output. If you remove that `\n`, the program will still find and print "empty words", but they will be "invisible" (since they have zero length). Alternatively, you can simply filter out zero-length words from the output.

If don't want your program to behave that way, you have to rewrite your code keeping in mind that separator characters can come in groups. You have to skip the whole contiguous group before starting to accumulate the next word. Alternatively, you can filter out zero-length words from the output.